# Opening a website in browser using Pcap.Net c#

Tags: c#, .net, spoofing, pcap.net

My aim is to open a website in browser with IP spoofing. In other words I want to open a website with the IP of my choice. I am creating a desktop application in c# .net. I have read that I need to use 3 way handshake for this kind of implementation.

Following is the code just for sending packets which I found.

```
HttpRequestLayer httpLayer = new HttpRequestLayer
{
     Version = HttpVersion.Version11,
     Header = new HttpHeader(new HttpContentLengthField(11)),
     Body = new Datagram(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world")),
     Method = new HttpRequestMethod(HttpRequestKnownMethod.Get),
     Uri = @"http://mywebsite.com/",
};
```

I am new to this kind of network related programming. I want an example related to 3 way handshake implemented in c#. Also kindly suggest me any related examples if any.

Comment: I suggest you start by sniffing regular website traffic and look at the packet one by one. Notes: 1. Make sure that even though you spoof the IP, you can still sniff the packets sent to that IP. 2. A big challenge would probably be following the TCP session, make sure you understand how TCP works and be careful with the details.

Comment: @brickner: Can you give me good tutorials or examples for doing this?Thanks..

Comment: I don't know of good tutorials to do all of that. You can learn how to use Pcap.Net in https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide&referringTitle=Home

Comment: @brickner: Thanks and yes I am doing this now.